# Upload data from excel sheet and insert it into oracle apex table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I need to load data from excel to table . i.e. upload excel from apex application and then insert this data into oracle database table. I have been advised to avoid plugin so am looking for oracle apex processed using which i can do this.

Any advice/steps/links to information would be very helpful.

Th file to be loaded is .xlsx .

Comment: Are you actually using APEX 5.1 like your tag suggests?  Normally, it would be suggested that you just use `apex_data_parser` to parse the Excel file (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aeapi/APEX_DATA_PARSER.html#GUID-07E9397C-DF26-40F7-AC73-F46961E1088A).  But if you're stuck on an old version of APEX, that may not be available